# How to click on facebook longin dialong window using Selenium tool

Tags: selenium, junit4

[image]

Hi All,

I'm new buddy to the selenium web automation tool. I'm stuck with an scenario were in I need to send log in credentials in the Facebook login window page to complete my test case. So please help out or provide some suggestion to pass the credentials and login to the Facebook account.

I tried out using the Selenium IDE and record my test script but while running the recorded script I'm unable to get access to that particular dialog window.

Below I had attached my scenario image

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you able to switch focus to the new window ?? By the way try switching to Webdriver instead of using IDE .

Comment: include some code of what you've tried please

Comment: Hi Anand, I tried the above in both way using IDE and using web driver but couldn't change my focus to the new window

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trails, I was able to achieved the above scenario by using the following below code.

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this one please

```
    //Store the current window handle
    String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

    //Perform the click operation that opens new window
    //switch to new window opened
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);

    }

    //Perform the actions on new window
    //close the new window, if that window no more required
    driver.close();

    //Swithc back to original browser (first window)
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);

    //continue with original browser (first window)
```